# I’m trying to include yaml files into app.yaml for Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, app.yaml

I want to separate secrets (API Keys, passwords) from app.yaml into their own separated yaml file which is not part of my github project repo.

I have no clue if it’s possible or what the syntax would be to include a file (or keys from another file). I tried searching on Google (for days) but could not find anything that satisfies my needs.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

app.yaml:

```
env_variables:
    INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME: example-database-name
    
includes:
    secrets.yaml
```

and than a secrets.yaml file with:

```
  DB_USER: root
  DB_PASS: foobar
  DB_NAME: example_name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the variables need to be inside `env_variables` block:

secrets.yaml

```
env_variables:
  DB_USER: 'root'
```

then include this file as you already do:

```
includes:
  - secrets.yaml
```

Although in long term I'd recommend to use [Secrets Manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager) for saving the secrets.

Comment: Thanks, this solves it! it's the dash before secrets.yaml that was the problem (that stopped it from compiling)